# when run on the emulater, after taking picture and pressing check to use the taked photo, it doesn't do anything..[Android]

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-camera

```
public class FulfillPhotoTaskActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


ImageView iv;
Uri outputFileUri;
Button takePhoto;
Button uploadPhoto;
Bitmap bmp;
Intent cameraIntent;
File file;
final static int cameraData = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fulfill_photo_task);
    initialize();


}
private void initialize() {
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    takePhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takePhoto);
    takePhoto.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_fulfill_photo_task, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/tmp");
    String folder = root.toString(); 
    file = new File(folder, "fileName" + ".jpg");
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, cameraData);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    }
}


}
```

When I run this program on the emulator, after taking a picture and pressing the check to use the taken photo, it doesn't do anything - it doesn't go to the `ImageView`.

Does this code have any bugs?

Comment: I nearly pulled my hair out trying to test a camera app on the emulator, but then realized that the emulator camera sucked and didn't work right.  When I tried it on a real device, my problems all went away!  I suggest you try it on a real device before trying to figure out the problem.

Comment: Not sure if it will help but you are using zero (your `cameraData` field) for the 'requestCode' when calling `startActivityForResult(...)`. I can't help feeling this can cause problems. Try a number such as 1234 (or anything other than 0).

Answer (score 0):

The Android emulator is full of bugs too numerous to count. This sounds simplistic, but have you tried this on an actual device? I've had plenty of bad juju on the emulator that just disappeared after going to the device.